# Abelianisation of Groupoids

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, groupoids

I was wondering what a good source for the properties (or even the existence) of the abelianisation of a (2-) groupoid would be? A naive construction would certainly be to abelianise the automorphisms (this is also mentioned [here](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2016/07/topological_crystals_part_2.html)) but maybe that isn't the best construction?

As for basic properties I'm curious about:  is this an exact (or rather $2$-exact) functor and adjoint to the inclusion-functor of groupoids into abelian groupoids (by which I should probably mean abelian objects in the category of categories?)

Comment: Depending on exactly how abelian you want the result to be, you can take the suspension spectrum, which more generally is the free “abelian group” on an $\infty$-groupoid in a suitable sense.